# Increasing clarity of Matplotlib graph output

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Im using `Matplotlib` and `Pandas`to create a pretty standard graph of two time-series data points. The problem is (see below), the data I'm interested in is after the large drop in values, I'd like to see a bit more clearly the difference between the green and red lines. Currently its a bit of a mess that is not very readable.

Are there any Matplotlib/Python/other tricks that can help with a problem like this?

[image]

Comment: (1) get rid of the markers, (2) log-scale the y-axis.

Comment: Be careful of log scale if your audience is not used to looking at it.  If you don't care about the spike, set the y limits to 0-100 and let it go off-scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think making the graph more clear is not what you should aim for. I think you should cut out the data that you want to see and make a graph of that.

Your problem is that you have a very high peak. Just cut away all values that are too high and make a new graph.

Since you did not show any of your code, I can only provide a pseudo example.

```
df[(df['green'] < 100])].plot()
```

This will remove any values in the series where the green is above 100, which seems to be a good threshold value.

You could even split this into two graphs, like this:

```
mask = df['green'] < 100
index_cutoff = np.argmax(df[mask])
dfhigh = df.loc[0:index_cutoff]
dflow = df.loc[index_cutoff:]
dfhigh.plot()
dflow.plot()
```

Probably a few mistakes in that code since I don't have your data to test with. But I hope you get my idea.